# REACT getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" when redirecting trough button Onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-router

I am a beginner with react, trying to make my app change screens on button click. I went through plenty of posts here on stack, but with no results.

My code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom' 
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {Card, Header, Button} from 'react-native-elements';  

import AddNews from './AddNews';

export default class App extends React.Component{

  onClick(){
    this.props.router.push("/addnews");
  }

   render(){
     return(

       <BrowserRouter>
       <Route exact path='/addnews' component={AddNews}/> 
       </BrowserRouter>

       <View>

         <Button title= "stlac" color = 'red' onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}></>

       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried different approaches, using withRouter, browserHistory, useHistory, almost everything I could find on here, but every single option gave me the same error. The error happens in the onClick functions, therefore I think, I am not passing the correct "this", but have no idea how should I change it or what should I do.

Thanks, Lukas

EDIT: Update after using arrow function :[empty props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rlap.png)

EDIT2: Answer is hidden in the comments.

Comment: you need to bind `this` to your `onClick` handler. Either  convert it to an arrow function, or use `.bind` inside the constructor

Comment: If you are beginner with React, I would strongly suggest you to write functional components instead of class components. This is the way to go with React. And you won't have to deal with `this` anymore

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, @HermitCrab the thing is, when I tried the functional approach, I was not able to fetch API because I couldn't find a workaround to it being asynchronous.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli can you please elaborate? I have no clue about arrow functions or binding this to handlers, I'm making this as a part of school assignment without any prior knowledge to JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your `onClick` to an **arrow function**, this will make `this` be your App component instance:

```
  onClick = () => {
    this.props.router.push("/addnews");
  }
```

Comment: Tried this now. When I log "this", I got nothing in props :/ updated the post to include screen of it

Comment: Try `this.props.history.push("/addnews");`

Comment: It's still the same :/

Comment: I think I know why. A push can only work for components that are a child of `<BrowserRouter`> but your `App` is not rendered inside `BrowserRouter`. Actually `BrowserRouter` is a child of your `App` so App doesn't have the extra props required for pushing a url

Comment: How do I make it render inside BrowserRouter? From my perspective, Its an element inside render atm.

Comment: The parent of `App` should render it inside `BrowserRouter`. Right now you have: `App -> BrowserRouter -> Route`  but what you need is `BrowserRouter -> App -> Route`

Comment: I love you, your example with arrows "hierarchy" made me think, in the App, I need to have just BrowserRouter Basically, the button couldn't be in the same class, or let's say, in the same render function,  as the BrowserRouter. Now it is like App->BroserRouter->Routes for all my pages, where each one is stored in a single .js file with its own class, and it works!